# Proof of Euclidian's algorithm for non-coprime numbers

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

This question is part of my assignment and I am really struggling with it.

*Let us now apply these steps to a more general situation. As before we will suppose that the Euclidean algorithm runs in $3$ steps.*

$$r_0 ÷ r_1 =m_1 R\;r_2$$

$$r_1 ÷ r_2 =m_2 R\;r_3$$

$$r_2 ÷ r_3 =m_3 R\;0$$

*Prove that $r_3$ is factor of $r_0$ and $r_1$.*

---

They have given the example of $\gcd(81,33) = 3$.

1. The questions is asking for a proof to show why $3$ (the GCD should be a factor of $15,33$ and $81$)
   You should have found that the last step of the algorithm gives 15 3 = 5R0. Use
   this to conclude that 3 is a factor of 15.
2. You should have found that the second step of the algorithm gives 33 15 = 2R3.
   Use this to conclude that 3 is a factor of 33 and 15.
3. You should have found that the first step of the algorithm gives 81 33 = 2R15. Use
   this to conclude that 3 is a factor of 81 and 33.

I understand that since 15 is directly divisible by 3 , 15 has one of it's factor as 3.
And intuitively also I understand that 33 and 81 has factors of 3, but I do not know how can I prove that with what they are asking me.

Comment: It's easier to follow if you write the actual divisions $r_0=m_1r_1+r_2$, $r_1=m_2r_2+r_3$, $r_2=m_3r_3$. Then the last relation means $r_3 \mid r_2$, and going backwards $r_3 \mid m_2r_2+r_3 = r_1$ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it.

$r_0\div r_1= m_1Rr_2 \implies r_0 = r_1\times m_1 + r_2$.

$r_1 \div r_2 = m_2Rr_3 \implies r_1 = m2\times r_2 + +r_3$

So $r_0 = r_1\times m_1 + r_2 = (m2\times r_2 +r_3)\times m_1 +r_2$

And $r_2\div r_3 = m_3R0\implies r_2 = m_3\times r_3$.

So $r_0 = r_1\times m_1 + r_2 = (m_2\times r_2 +r_3)\times m_1 +r_2=$

$(m_2\times (m_3\times r_3) +r_3)\times m_1 +(m_3\times r_3) =$

$[(m_2\times m_2 + 1)\times m_1 + m_3]\times r_3$.

So $r_3$ is a factor of $r_0$.

Do the same for $r_1$